# Inserting array elements in parentheses

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I got a sorted 2D array [[0,1],[1,1],[1,2],[2,3]] in javascript.
I have to convert this array into a string with each element separated by a pair of parentheses, eg. the above array should return a string as "(0,1)(1,1)(1,2)(2,3)"

i tried converting the array into string using join and tried inserting the parentheses at the begining and the end using traditional approach..

```
var elem = elements.join(')(').split();
elem.unshift('(');
elem.push(')');
console.log(elem.join());
```

but output i'm getting is a string as "(,0,0)(1,1)(1,1)(2,3,)"
how to remove the unwanted commas in between?

Comment: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
console.log([[0,1],[1,1],[1,2],[2,3]].map(a => `(${a})`).join(''));

//or

console.log([[0,1],[1,1],[1,2],[2,3]].reduce((result, item) => result + `(${item})`, ''));
```